# Is Facebook to Facebook (mobile application call) encrypted?

Tags: encryption, man-in-the-middle, facebook, voip

I understand Facebook uses WebRtc to send voice data packet in network if any one end client is on the browser. Use of DTLS packets can be seen in captured (wireshark) file.
But in case of mobile app to mobile app, we don't see any sign that it is encrypted. We can see some encrypted key running, but that cannot confirm that whether that key is used for RTP packet encryption or to keep the SIP (or other signal controlling packet) session alive.
I dont want to believe that Facebook doesn't encrypt the calls, but can anybody please confirm if there is any way to confirm it?

Comment: Is is encrypted client to server, but not client to client

Comment: @Natanael,Can you please clarify bit more ? We can see it sends RTP packet peer to peer, of course signalling control (SIP or any other) is client server. Do you mean the RTP packets are not encrypted ?

Comment: I might have mixed up some things. Does Wireshark show you if it is encrypted or not? I think WebRTC is encrypted by default.

Comment: I doubt facebook uses webrtc in mobile to mobile (messenger) communication. Of course it uses it when communicated from browser. So, no way i could identify whether it is encrypted or not.